# AsyncTask: not modified from a background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, adapter

AsyncTask: I removed all possible ui operation in background thread, still got those kind of exception after run 5 or 6 times. please help me.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131427449, class
>   android.widget.ListView) with Adapter...

Comment: We need to see some code if we are to help you.

Comment: show some of your background thread code..

Comment: minimal (not) working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, It works. I used a handler to add item while publishing progress(i.e. AsyncTask + Handler):

```
private void addAdapter(Item item)
{
    Message message = addhandler.obtainMessage();
    message.what = 1;
    message.obj = item;
    addhandler.sendMessage(message);
}

private Handler addhandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
            if (msg.obj != null) {
                _adapter.add((Item) msg.obj);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `notifyDataChanged()` or `requestLayout();` from your `UI` Thread.

Comment: requestLayout()? what is that?